# How to get grouped sums listed on the same row?

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

I have below mock up data,

```
itemNum    itemName       type        count  
-------------------------------------------------  
1111       A001           1           2  
1111       A001           1           4  
1111       A001           3           2  
1111       A001           3           5  
1111       A001           3           3  
1111       A001           3           6  
2222       A002           1           3  
2222       A002           1           5  
2222       A002           2           4  
2222       A002           2           7  
2222       A002           3           8  
2222       A002           3           9
```

i need the sums of one item per type listed in the same row,(there will be only 3 types, so will have three columns  sum1, sum2, sum3.)  The result i need is ,

```
itemNum    itemName      sum1      sum2      sum3  
--------------------------------------------------  
1111        A001         6          7         9
2222        A002         8          11        17
```

How do i write the oracle sql script ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot` as following:

> ```
> Select * from
> (Select * from your_table)
> Pivot
> (
> Sum(count) 
> for type in (1 as sum_1, 2 as sum_2, 3 as sum_3)
> )
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select itemnum, itemname,
       sum(case when type = 1 then count end) as sum_1,
       sum(case when type = 2 then count end) as sum_2,
       sum(case when type = 3 then count end) as sum_4
from t
group by itemnum, itemname;
```